# Sourcetree offers you to choose CredentialHelperSelector

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

A window is constantly popping up in Sourcetree. What should I do with it, what do these options mean, and why are they repeated?
[This window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ9Yw.png)

Answer (score 6):

One solution for Windows -

- Install https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows (i.e. https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/1.20.0 at time of answer)
- When the credential window popups - choose manager-core (or core-manager) and select always use this (or equivalent)

Hopefully that pop-up will now go away.

Comment: Is there any documentation explains what each "helper" is for?